# Can't open certain websites with safari

Tags: ios, windows, safari

It is impossible to access some websites with safari. I tried on Windows. I just get `Safari can't open the site because it can't establish a secure connection` the site uses SSL though.

I can open it with all other browsers, including chrome, firefox, edge and internet explorer. I just installed safari yesterday.

I was able to find some old solutions from 2010 but nothing works so far. What might be the cause? Is this a known bug?

Comment: Which websites?

Comment: e.g. https://www.botec.de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted our hoster. They said that it is not working, because safari browser for windows does not support the newest versions of TLS and the browser is not getting updates since 6 years. We are using TLS 1.2 on our webserver.

Answer (score 1):

The site you are trying to connect to requires SNI support in the browser. The certificate used when SNI is not supported is not trusted. The web filter I use marks the site as compromised for the reasons found [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.botec.de) (Certificate #2).

Unfortunately, Safari on Windows does not support SNI. I can't speak about its support on iPad.